# Creating a pie chart from a multi-pickist field

Tags: reporting, picklist, multi-select, charts

It appears Salesforce stores multi-picklist values as semicolon-separated values. I want to create a pie chart based on the individual values in a multi-picklist field.

For example, if I have field called `Tools` and a record has a value like `Hammer;Drill;Punch` I want my pie chart to count 1 for each of these three values. So if this was the only record, the charge would have 3 slices: 1 for Hammer, 1 for Drill, and 1 for Punch.

Can this be done without a lot of fuss?

Comment: Open to use VF page? This can be done using Apex:chart

Comment: I'm open to it, but am looking for a way to do this using the standard reporting features.